# How to NOT cache loader output?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack caches loaders by default

Say, I've the following loader,

```
module.exports = function(source) {
  // Note I'm explicitly saying not to cache
  this.cacheable(false);
  return 'module.exports = ' + Math.random();
}
```

Every time I `require('./asset.ext')`, I get the same random number. How can I get different output from the loader for the same resource.

#### Where do I plan to use it ?

I want to `require('./image.png')` in JS and CSS. In css, `css-loader`, helps me to achieve this where `url(./image.png)` is treated as requires. And loaders don't know about the issuer. So I wrote a plugin that tells the loader about the issuer and works fine. But when I start using it in both CSS and JS, whichever gets called first, the loader caches the output, and returns the same output. I want to prevent this. For JS I want to return an object, and for CSS I want to return a string.

Comment: I think the reason is because it's a singleton. It's executed only on the first time, this is by design in a CommonJS world. You should wrap it into a function that you can execute on runtime, which should give you on every call another number.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky, but why not just create a symlink from `image.png` to `image-copy.png`, then use one filename for JS and the other filename for CSS? As far as the require is concerned, they're two different files so it'll load it again.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question,

Instead of trying to not cache the loader, I wrote an override `toString` for the Object returned, so that when required in CSS, this method is triggered and I get my required string.

Implemented here - https://github.com/boopathi/image-size-loader/blob/master/index.js#L14-L19

```
module.exports = JSON.stringify(o);
module.exports.toString = () => JSON.stringify(o.src);
```